# How does "getchar()" know what character to read in C?

Tags: c, getchar

I have just started learning C and I came across an example which used the function `getchar` in a while loop. I don't understand how the `getchar` knows which char to return if it takes in no parameters. It was used in a way similar to this:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: Likely getting with an inferred context such as the keyboard or standard input device. On many systems keyboard combo Ctrl + C is the EOF (outside of a GUI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, take note of the function prototype:

```
int getchar(void);
```

The `getchar()` function **always** reads the *next* character from the [*standard input*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) stream.

It doesn't *need* any arguments because it only ever does that one thing. In particular, observe from the [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getchar.html):

> The getchar() function shall be equivalent to getc(stdin).

So `getchar()` is really the same as `getc()`, only that `getc()` allows you to *specify* the input stream.

Your confusion lies in the fact that the `getchar()` function has no explicit input parameters (in the form of function arguments -- its a `void` function) and yet it can return all sorts of different results to you.

Its "input" depends on the *user input* instead, much like `scanf()`, `fgets()` and even command-line arguments through the `argv` array.